# How to get true small-caps from a webfont from Google-fonts

Tags: css, webfonts, typography, google-webfonts

I'm using the [*Alegreya* font family](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Alegreya) from Google Fonts in a website. It seems like Google strips out the small-caps font feature, so although Alegreya *has* small-caps (see below), they don't seem to work with Google Fonts. How can I get [**true** small-caps](https://practicaltypography.com/small-caps.html) in this scenario (font from Google Fonts)?

Alegreya has true small-caps (as OpenType feature) in it, and also has a sister small-caps-only family, [Alegreya SC](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Alegreya+SC). I've downloaded the Regular font from both families (directly from Google Fonts) and compared Alegreya-with-small-caps with Alegreya SC. They are identical, e.g., Alegreya *has the same small-caps* as its sister. But when I try CSS below:

```css
.variant-smcp {
  font-family: Alegreya, serif; /* Alegreya from Google Fonts */
  font-variant: small-caps; /* should use OpenType smcp feature */
}
```

I only get fake small-caps (e.g., capitals shrinked by the browser).

A workaround would be to import both Alegreya and Alegreya SC, using the latter without setting any `font-variant` when needed. But this comes with a big problem for me: it *doubles* the number of requested fonts. And overall it seems a bit clumsy to import another font just for small-caps, if my font *already has* these baked in.

**Edit**: I've also tested using `font-feature-settings: "smcp" on;`, with exactly same result: fake small-caps, from an `smcp`-capable font (Alegreya). And I've tested all these things in Firefox 66 (for Windows and for Android), with exactly same result. (Thanks @Parapluie)

Comment: I think your workaround is the solution without involving CSS as you'll need the base font and then the other font to sugar the base font.

Comment: Really looking for a solution to this one as well. See the discussion here: https://github.com/googlefonts/noto-fonts/issues/1465#issuecomment-653207286 where the google font I'm using is also verified to have small caps, but only fake small caps show up in browsers.

Comment: @JonFergus Google strips out `smcp` font feature in Google Fonts. I found and tested this after trying and failing last year. I don't remember which command I used against fonts (downloaded directly from Google Fonts) to discover that, but perhaps you can use [FontTools](https://github.com/fonttools/fonttools). After all, I'm hosting my own font files, optimized in [Font Squirrel](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator), getting less server requests with a little more bytes in total font sizes.